# Linker error when using a struct variable

Tags: c, linker

When I try to compile the program below, I get a linker error:

```
/tmp/ccAikIsV.o    undefined reference to uvlc_encode_blockline
```

I have all the structures video_controller_t .. etc declared and typedefed

```
int uvlc_encode_blockline(struct video_controller_t* controller, const struct    vp_api_picture_t* blockline, bool_t picture_complete );
int uvlc_decode_blockline(struct video_controller_t* controller,struct vp_api_picture_t* picture, bool_t* got_image );
int uvlc_update( struct video_controller_t* controller );
int uvlc_cache( struct video_controller_t* controller,struct video_stream_t* ex_stream);

const uvlc_codec_t uvlc_codec = {
uvlc_encode_blockline,
uvlc_decode_blockline,
uvlc_update,
uvlc_cache,
{ 0 }
};
```

Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

---

#### Update

I agree that we should define the function to tell linker to get it and use it. When I did something similar, I did not get any error. I declared function pointer:

```
typedef C_RESULT (encode_blockline_fc)(struct video_controller_t controller,
                                       const struct vp_api_picture_t* blockline,
                                       bool_t picture_complete);
```

and used it in struct below:

```
typedef struct _video_codec_t
{
    encode_blockline_fc encode_blockline;
    decode_blockline_fc decode_blockline;
    update_fc update;
    cache_stream_fc cache_stream;
} video_codec_t;
```

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the syntax below:

```
const uvlc_codec_t uvlc_codec = {
uvlc_encode_blockline,
uvlc_decode_blockline,
uvlc_update,
uvlc_cache,
{ 0 }
};
```

---

I agree that we should define the function to tell linker to get it and use it. when I did something similar, I did not get any error. I declared function pointer
    typedef C_RESULT (encode_blockline_fc)( struct video_controller_t controller, const struct vp_api_picture_t* blockline, bool_t picture_complete );
and used it in struct below 
    typedef struct _video_codec_t { encode_blockline_fc encode_blockline; decode_blockline_fc decode_blockline; update_fc update; cache_stream_fc cache_stream; }video_codec_t

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the syntax below:
const uvlc_codec_t uvlc_codec = {
uvlc_encode_blockline,
uvlc_decode_blockline,
uvlc_update,
uvlc_cache,
{ 0 }
};

Comment: where are the functions: uvlc_encode_blockline,uvlc_decode_blockline,uvlc_update,uvlc_cache?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax. If there was, you would not get a linker error; you would get a compiler error. We can argue that there should not be a leading underscore on the structure tag (identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved for 'the implementation'), but that's minor and many people flout that rule, at their own risk, of course. The problem is not syntax at all. The problem is that the linker cannot find the function that you told it to use to provide the pointer to function in the structure. Which file is it implemented in? Why didn't you link that file as well?

Comment: IIRC, the const modifier behaves differently in C++. Are you by any chance compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: Hi Wildplasser, I am using gcc not g++. So I was wondering about the syntax const uvlc_codec_t...Also, if it was linker error, it should complain for  typedef C_RESULT (encode_blockline_fc)( struct video_controller_t controller, const struct vp_api_picture_t* blockline, bool_t picture_complete ); when function encode_blockline_fc is not defined. But it doesnot

Answer (score 0):

The linker complains about an unresolved reference to a function, not about the struct. You should pass the linker an object file or a library that contains this function, or define it in the current compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibility of Linker Error-

**1-** If you fail to include all of the necessary object files in the linking process.

**2-** If there are more than one definition for a class, function, or variable.

So check it.

Answer (score 0):

You've told the compiler that the function `uvlc_encode_blockline()` exists somewhere, but when the linker goes to look for it, it can't actually find it — so it complains that it can't find it.

The declaration is enough to let the source file compile to object code.  To link the program, you actually have to define the function and link the object file that contains the definition in with the object file that references it.

Comment: I agree with you about this. But when I did something similar, I did not get any error. I declared function pointer                           typedef C_RESULT (*encode_blockline_fc)( struct video_controller_t* controller, const struct vp_api_picture_t* blockline, bool_t picture_complete );and used it in struct below                typedef struct _video_codec_t { 
  encode_blockline_fc encode_blockline; 
  decode_blockline_fc decode_blockline; 
  update_fc           update; 
  cache_stream_fc     cache_stream; 
}video_codec_t ;